# Problems with launch program' ' does not exit

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20, launch

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbM9C.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXkO3.png)

I have tried everything in my power to configure the settings of VSCode or compiled using the right standard. I'm following lesson 0.12 on learncpp.com. Eventually things just still stay the same with it any ideas?

Here is my code btw:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <span>

struct Foo
{
    int a{ };
    int b{ };
    int c{ };
};

consteval int sum(std::span<const int>    a)
{
    int s{ 0 };
    for (auto n : a)
        s += n;
    return s;
}

auto sum(auto x, auto y) -> decltype(x + y)
{
    return x + y;
}

int main() 
{
    constexpr std::array a{ 3, 2, 1 };
    constexpr int s{ sum(a) };
    Foo f1( .a = 1, .c = 3);
    std::cout << sum(f1.a, f1.c) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried everything in my power to configure the settings of VSCode or compiled using the right standard. I also tried updating gcc as well.

Comment: See how the output says "Build finished with error(s)", and there's another tab named "Problems" with the number 5 next to it? I'd start there. It's very common for the final executable to not exist when the compiler didn't create it due to errors.

Comment: Show your `tasks.json` and your errors both as text

Comment: In your case, you should configure the `task.json` file to build your project, using the same parameters GCC needs. Another way, and it's my favorite, is to use CMAKE or MAKE, whatever you like, to build your program and configure `launche.json` to run it or debug it, don't forget to build your project to support debug process. But, first of all, share the `task.json` to see how you are setting the parameters to build the project.